# Puzzling Output When Reading Memory Address In VB

Tags: vb.net, memory

So I have this code

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1

    Const PROCESS_WM_READ As Integer = &H10

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll")>
    Public Shared Function OpenProcess(dwDesiredAccess As Integer, bInheritHandle As Boolean, dwProcessId As Integer) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll")>
    Public Shared Function ReadProcessMemory(hProcess As Integer, lpBaseAddress As Integer, lpBuffer As Byte(), dwSize As Integer, ByRef lpNumberOfBytesRead As Integer) As Boolean
    End Function

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim notepadProcess As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("GeometryDash")(0)
        Dim processHandle As IntPtr = OpenProcess(PROCESS_WM_READ, False, notepadProcess.Id)

        Dim bytesRead As Integer = 0
        Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(23) {}

        'The address in this line is hard-coded.  Use whatever is appropriate for your situation.
        ReadProcessMemory(CInt(processHandle), 117317672, buffer, buffer.Length, bytesRead)

        MsgBox(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer))

    End Sub
End Class
```

It outputs 2 or 3 weird Japanese characters, the address "117317672" is "06FE2028" in decimal. I think it's not liking how I'm giving it the address, how should I put in the address?

Comment: How do you know there will be a UTF-16 encoded string occupying 23 bytes at that address? (For a start UTF-16 is always an even number of bytes.)

Comment: You mean it's 06FE2028 in *hexi* decimal. As for the 23 byte length, 23 is the upper bound of the array, so it has a length of 24, so that's ok.  It seems odd to be reading bytes out of a fixed location within a process though.